# Unable to start Strapi on MacOS PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pm2, strapi, postgresql-10

**System**
- Node.js version: v10.19.0
- NPM version: 6.13.4
- Strapi version: 3.0.0-Beta.2
- Database: PostgreSQL 10.11 
- Operating system: MacOS Catalina

**Describe the bug**
I am trying to run local Strapi on my Mac. `npm run build` works well. However, it has some problems with 'start' and 'develop'. When I am trying to start it by `pm2 start npm --name "CMS" -- start`, it keeps restarting. I have checked the app OUT-logs and there is a couple of errors e.g.

```
{ error: syntax error at or near "url"
    at Connection.parseE (/usr/local/var/www/trip4share-cms/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:602:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/usr/local/var/www/trip4share-cms/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:399:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/var/www/trip4share-cms/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  name: 'error',
  length: 92,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '50',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1128',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror' }
[2020-04-06T21:30:50.439Z] warn The SQL database indexes haven't been generated successfully. Please enable the debug mode for more details.
{ error: syntax error at or near "name"
    at Connection.parseE (/usr/local/var/www/trip4share-cms/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:602:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/usr/local/var/www/trip4share-cms/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:399:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/var/www/trip4share-cms/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  name: 'error',
  length: 93,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '49',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1128',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror' }
[2020-04-06T21:30:50.439Z] warn The SQL database indexes haven't been generated successfully. Please enable the debug mode for more details.
```

When I am running `npm run start` I am getting the following error.

```
23 ],
  __knexQueryUid: '4301a348-badc-484f-a418-4f0f5ab4a2a6',
  sql:
   'update "core_store" set "key" = ?, "environment" = ?, "tag" = ?, "value" = ?, "type" = ? where "id" = ?',
  returning: undefined }
{ method: 'insert',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings:
   [ 'development',
     'plugin_upload_provider',
     '',
     'object',
     '{"provider":"local","name":"Local server","enabled":true,"sizeLimit":1000000}' ],
  __knexQueryUid: '797edf19-aaab-43ff-a2f3-7c25519fb700',
  sql:
   'insert into "core_store" ("environment", "key", "tag", "type", "value") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) returning "id"',
  returning: 'id' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 'plugin_users-permissions_advanced', '', '', 1 ],
  __knexQueryUid: '51c83527-e289-4c2b-bb0c-48fe7fd34d86',
  sql:
   'select "core_store".* from "core_store" where "core_store"."key" = ? and "core_store"."environment" = ? and "core_store"."tag" = ? limit ?' }
[2020-04-06T22:20:17.365Z] error error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "core_store_pkey"
    at Connection.parseE (/usr/local/var/www/trip4share-cms/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:602:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/usr/local/var/www/trip4share-cms/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:399:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/var/www/trip4share-cms/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! trip4share-cms@1.0.0 start: `strapi start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the trip4share-cms@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Lord-of-the-Mac/.npm/_logs/2020-04-06T22_20_17_400Z-debug.log
```

The remote version on Linux works well. What should I check?

Comment: did you finish it?